# How to make @op run in sequence when job invoked from sensor?

Tags: dagster

can you please help me overcome the below issue
i have an sensor [my_sensor] defined on a job [my_job].
[my_job] executes op [my_op] which requires an input [filename] from sensor which i am passing from sensor using

```
yield RunRequest(
    run_key=None,
    run_config=RunConfig(
        ops={"my_op": FileConfig(filename="customer_name")}
    ),
)
```

[my_op] returns an dynamic output. I want to process all the dynamic outputs sequentially not in parallel.
I am trying with the below config on job but still the dynamic output mappings are running in parallel

```
@job(
    config={
        "ops": {"my_op": {"config": {"filename": "my_sensor"}}},
        "execution": {
            "config": {
                "multiprocess": {
                    "max_concurrent": 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
)
def my_job():
    file_list = my_op()
    success_query, failed_query = file_list.map(write_json_file)
    success_query.map(success)
    failed_query.map(failure)
```

Comment: I am trying to achieve the same thing, did you find how to do it?